# Avoid repetition in lexing when using parsec

Tags: haskell, parsec

The Parsec documentation has an example of using `makeTokenParser` to build a lexer:

```
module Main where

 import Text.Parsec
 import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P
 import Text.Parsec.Language (haskellDef)

 -- The parser
 ...

 expr  =   parens expr
       <|> identifier
       <|> ...


 -- The lexer
 lexer       = P.makeTokenParser haskellDef    

 parens      = P.parens lexer
 braces      = P.braces lexer
 identifier  = P.identifier lexer
 reserved    = P.reserved lexer
 ...
```

In "The lexer" block, every `P.*` is applied to lexer so that one can avoid repeating that in "The parser" block. However repeating that for every token is still tedious. Is there some way to avoid the repetition even more? I was thinking to implicitly apply lexer everywhere in "The parser", but am at lost how to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general [syntax for pattern matching on records](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching#Introduction_to_records) in Haskell (I started by noticing that all of `P.parens`, `P.braces`, etc. are record projection functions - you can see that by looking at the [docs](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec-Token.html).) . You can use that here

```
P.TokenParser { P.parens      = parens
              , P.braces      = braces
              , P.identifier  = identifier
              , P.reserved    = reserved
              } = P.makeTokenParser haskellDef
```

## EDIT

As ErikR has pointed out, it you don't just want *some* of the parsers, but you want all 29 of the `GenTokenParser` fields brought into global scope, you can enable the `RecordWildCards` extension and just write

```
 P.TokenParser {..} = P.makeTokenParser haskellDef
```

Comment: If you enable `RecordWildCards`, you can use just `P.TokenParser{..} = lexer` at the top level to define all of the record fields.